# Do we have to register all js files in functions.php in wordpress site?

Tags: wordpress

I actually am a newbie to wordpress, i am converting an html website to wordpress template. There are alot of js file in my js directory but all of them are not loaded on every page. What I want to know is that do we have to register all js files in functions.php and use wp_head in our head tag to load them?

Answer (score 0):

For theme you need to put below code in your functions.php

```
function wpb_adding_scripts() {
    wp_register_script('my_amazing_script', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/amazing_script.js', array('jquery'),'1.1', true);
    wp_enqueue_script('my_amazing_script');
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wpb_adding_scripts' )
```

If you are creating your custom plugin below code will help you.

```
function wpb_adding_scripts() {
    wp_register_script('my_amazing_script', plugins_url('amazing_script.js', __FILE__), array('jquery'),'1.1', true);
    wp_enqueue_script('my_amazing_script');
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wpb_adding_scripts' );
```

For more understanding of wp_enqueue_script read below two links :

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/
http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-properly-add-javascripts-and-styles-in-wordpress/

As you are beginner i can say wpbeginner will be good site for you they give the all understanding very clearly